# C# WinForms - ComboBox que autocompleta (filtra) ao digitar

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Eu tenho um ComboBox (cmbBairro) com os nomes dos bairros da minha cidade, que carrega os valores de um List (_ListBairros). Quando o usuário tentar buscar um bairro, digitando, gostaria que os valores do ComboBox fossem filtrados, independente da posição dos caracteres digitados!

Ao digitar, por exemplo: vis.

O ComboBox filtraria:

Boa **Vis**ta

Jardim **Vis**ta Alegre ...

Como faço isso?

Comment: Veja esta implementação: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631196/ComboBox-with-Suggest-Ability-based-on-Substring-S @Marconi é uma aplicação Windows (Winforms) e não Web. :)

Comment: Veja este outro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSBniHq5_zY

Comment: Opa blz, Da uma olhada nesse link ele faz o que você procura:
(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16285/Auto-Complete-ComboBox)
Nesse site você pode baixar o código e colocar no seu sistema. Correção:
Eu abaixei ele e apenas filtra do começo do texto

Comment: @HStackOverflow o código que vc citou faz exatamente o que eu quero... Só faltou dar um HIGHLIGHT na substring que está sendo digitada :D Obrigado

Comment: Por nada. @LeandroSJRP se possível poste o código como resposta para ajudar outros usuários com a mesma dúvida. ;)

Comment: Claro, assim que eu terminar a implementação eu postarei aqui! Abraço!

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver seu problema? Caso não tenha resolvido ainda basta mudar a propriedade AutoCompleteMode do ComboBox  para SuggestAppend, e pronto. Não precisa de nem de código. Se serviu marque como resposta. T+

Comment: O AutoComplete padrão só completa pelo começo da string não em qualquer lugar.

Comment: Pode usar o **combobox** do **jqueryui** que faz exatamente o que você precisa. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem se você queria que filtrasse na ComboBox ou na ListBox, então fiz os dois, esse filtra direto na ComboBox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string[] bairros = new string[] {
            "Acari",
            "Anchieta",
            "Barros Filho",
            "Bento Ribeiro",
            "Brás de Pina",
            "Bonsucesso",
            "Campinho",
            "Cavalcanti",
            "Cascadura",
            "Coelho Neto",
            "Colégio",
            "Complexo do Alemão",
            "Cordovil",
            "Costa Barros",
            "Engenheiro Leal",
            "Engenho da Rainha",
            "Guadalupe",
            "Higienópolis",
            "Honório Gurgel",
            "Irajá",
            "Jardim América",
            "Madureira",
            "Marechal Hermes",
            "Manguinhos",
            "Oswaldo Cruz"
        };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ListBairros.Items.AddRange(bairros);
        cmbBairro.TextChanged += CmbBairro_TextChanged;
    }
    private void CmbBairro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string texto = cmbBairro.Text;
        int a = cmbBairro.Items.Count;          
        if (a > 0) {
           int i = 0;
           while (i < a) {
                cmbBairro.Items.RemoveAt(0);                      
                i++;
          }
       }
        if (texto != "") {
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(texto, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (string lugar in bairros) {
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match resultado = regex.Match(lugar);
                if (resultado.Value != "") {
                    cmbBairro.Items.Add(lugar);
                }
            }
        }         
    }
}
```

Esse filtra na ListBox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string[] bairros = new string[] {
            "Acari",
            "Anchieta",
            "Barros Filho",
            "Bento Ribeiro",
            "Brás de Pina",
            "Bonsucesso",
            "Campinho",
            "Cavalcanti",
            "Cascadura",
            "Coelho Neto",
            "Colégio",
            "Complexo do Alemão",
            "Cordovil",
            "Costa Barros",
            "Engenheiro Leal",
            "Engenho da Rainha",
            "Guadalupe",
            "Higienópolis",
            "Honório Gurgel",
            "Irajá",
            "Jardim América",
            "Madureira",
            "Marechal Hermes",
            "Manguinhos",
            "Oswaldo Cruz"
        };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ListBairros.Items.AddRange(bairros);
        cmbBairro.TextChanged += CmbBairro_TextChanged;
    }

    private void CmbBairro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string texto = cmbBairro.Text;
        _ListBairros.Items.Clear();            
        if (texto != "") {
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(texto, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (string lugar in bairros) {
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match resultado = regex.Match(lugar);
                if (resultado.Value != "") {
                    _ListBairros.Items.Add(lugar);
                }
            }
        }         
    }
}
```

Dentro da string[] bairros é onde fica os bairros.

Esse é minha primeira participação no StackOverflow, desculpe-me qualquer erro :P

Comment: Muito bom @Roberto Araujo... faltou um detalhe: No evento TextChanged tem um if: if(texto !="").... eu adicionei um else: cmbBairro.Items.AddRange(bairros);